# Do prediction with CHAID in R

Tags: r, decision-tree, predict

I have build a model with CHAID. Now I want to use it to predict a variable - like I would do it with tree() or rpart():

```
MA_CHAID <- chaid(Data$target
              ~ Data$factor1
              + Data$factor2,
              control = chaid_control(minprob = 0.001,
                                      minsplit = 500,minbucket = 200),
              data = Data
               )

Data$MA_predict <- predict(MA_CHAID, Data)
```

But I get this Error message:

> Error in '$<-.data.frame'('*tmp*', MA_predict, value = c(1L, 1L,  : 
>   replacement has 124855 rows, data has 379031

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The CHAID tree was built including predictors with missing values.

The algorithm excluded all rows with any missing values. That's why the model was built with only half of the cases.

My next try will be to use "missing" as a category of its own.